# Reading lines into a list of lists

Tags: java, csv

If the lines of my file contains elements separated by comma, Can I have a buffered reader automatically plug in the elements into a list?

Or do I do a `readline` then call a `string.split` method?

E.g. My file has.

```
1, dog, abc, 10pm
2, cat, abc, 11pm
```

I want a list of lists out of my file so I can call the elements individually

Comment: Do yo really want to split elements separated by commas? Or do you want to actually wantto read one of the several formats called "CSV"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do for your case is to read a line first, and then use `split()`, as all the lines are formatted exactly alike. And use `ArrayList` of `String[]` to make your list of lists.

Example using BufferedReader:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"));
            while(in.ready()) {
                String line = in.readLine();
                String[] parts = line.split(", ");
                ArrayList<String> lineList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String s : parts) {
                    lineList.add(s);
                }
                myList.add(lineList);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }

        for(ArrayList<String> elem : myList) {
            for(String item : elem) {
                System.out.print(item + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Using Scanner (incomplete example):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("foo.txt"));
        in.useDelimiter(", ");

        while(in.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(in.next());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge, not unless you implement your own BufferedReader... though there might be one that takes  lambda in Java 8

Answer (score 0):

The interface of `BufferedReader` does not support reading directly into a list and less into a list of lists. You will have at least to do the split by yourself.

As of `java8` you can use [BufferedReader.lines()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) to get stream of line which you will have to split, tranform to a list and add to a list of lists:

```
public List<List<String>> readAsListOfLists8(String file) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        return br.lines().map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split("[, ]+")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

If you are running in `java7` you can use [Files.readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) to get a list of lines:

```
public List<List<String>> readAsListOfLists7(String file) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    List<List<String>> ll = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file))) {
        ll.add(Arrays.asList(line.split("[, ]+")));
    }
    return ll;
}
```

For lower versions of java use your solution.